# switch subtree to different remote branch

Tags: git, subtree

Consider this part of a repository of mine:

```
/
 myproject
 django -> django/master (django/django @github)
 ... other dependencies
```

django is a subtree that I merged following this howto: [How to use the subtree merge strategy](http://kernel.at/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html)

Now I found out that another dependency is incompatible with the current master of django and I want to switch to django/1.1.x for that reason. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submodule merely points at a commit.  Check out the proper commit, and add it to the parent module, and commit in the parent.

Comment: I'm using subtrees (not submodules) - so I don't think it'll work like this.

Comment: Ahh, what you'll have to do then is go back to the commit before your subtree commit, then merge in the new django, then replay all your commits on top of that (using `git rebase -i` and ignoring the commit that brought the other django in).